# How to initialize DateTime value on TextFormField like initialValue property in Dart?

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, initialization

I'm trying to use a template for making a task manager in flutter for an upcoming project, my main problem resides in the method to create a new task, which gets an error when I try to use the floating button.

When I try to create a new task, the app throws the following:

Image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeZdS.jpg

Here's the terminal message when the error happens:

Image Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FR6Lr.jpg

The error occurs in line 135 of my file "add_new_task.dart" in which the template adds a new task to the main homepage of the application, where I can edit or delete the task whenever I want. From what I understand the template and the flutter version are quite old, so I assume back then you didn't new to initialize the value.

Image Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmNh6.jpg

Around this line of code:

```
      Text('Due date', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2),
        TextFormField(
          onTap: () {
            _pickUserDueDate();
          },
          readOnly: true,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: _selectedDate == DateTime.utc(2020,1,1)
                ? 'Provide your due date'
                : DateFormat.yMMMd().format(_selectedDate).toString(),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
```

First I thought that initializing the value with the property "initialValue" would do the trick, like this:

`initialValue: _selectedDate = DateTime.now(),`

and that would've been it, however, it seems I can't do that since "initialValue" only accepts Strings as values, then I thought casting or converting the value would also work using the formatted, creating a final variable with the date of today, a final DateFormat for converting the DateTime and a call to the variable where I needed the string for the "initialValue":

```
final DateTime now = DateTime.now()
final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
//...a lot of code...//
String formatted = formatter.format(now);
//...
initialValue: _selectedDate=formatted,
```

Sadly that didn't work also, so I'm stuck here not knowing how to initialize the variable, and I'm suspecting the same problem will arise with _selectedTime when _selectedDate is solved, so my question for this conundrum is, how can I initialize the variable _selectedDate in the TextFormField widget? would the same problem happen in the variable _selectedTime?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You should set _selectedDate = formatted before you put in the initialValue, or else you will get that error.

So something like this:

```
_selectedDate = formatted;
//...
initialValue: _selectedDate,
```

Comment: If this answer helped you please mark it as the correct answer.